# Moving from position A to position B slowly with animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple jQuery animation using `fadein` and it works but once faded in... I wish to MOVE using TOP property 30 pixels upwards, but slowly.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('#Friends').fadeIn("slow");
```

I have both jQuery and jQuery UI loaded...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use jquery [animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) and give it a long duration say 2000

```
$("#Friends").animate({ 
        top: "-=30px",
      }, duration );
```

The -= means that the animation will be relative to the current top position.

Note that the `Friends` element must have position set to relative in the css:

```
#Friends{position:relative;}
```

Comment: no it doesn't seem to work.. I have the following.. (tried top also )

      $("#Friends").animate({ 'margin-top': "-=100px" }, "slow");

reason is that my code is like this

      <div id="Friends" style="width: 133px; margin-left: 19px; margin-top: -30px; background-image: url(content/images/friends.png);

Comment: this is an old prototype i was using... but wish to change to jquery..the prototype worked.

var friends= document.getElementById('Friends');

new Effect.Move(friends, { duration: 0.6, x: 0, y: -100, mode: 'relative' });

Comment: fixed .. its because i didn't have relative set as position

Comment: You can also chain this by adding multiple calls to animate().animate() after each other.

Answer (score 22):

You can animate it after the fadeIn completes using the callback as shown below:

```
$("#Friends").fadeIn('slow',function(){
  $(this).animate({'top': '-=30px'},'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand why other answers are about relative coordinates change, not absolute like OP asked in title.

```
$("#Friends").animate( {top:
  "-=" + (parseInt($("#Friends").css("top")) - 100) + "px"
} );
```