# How can I make an image move positions in HTML?

Tags: html, animation

I know, I am crazy, considering I am literally just learning HTML. But I am attempting to design a website for my brother, and he REALLY wants this. Please be very directional with your responses. I am using this JQuery thing to fade in and out a picture, so maybe I can use a similar thing to do this?

By the way, I would like the image to slide to it's position, not just move in a flash.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't even know JQuery and yet I'm pretty sure what you are asking for is built in. Have you considered glancing at the documentation? Or maybe shoot your brother a link to the documentation?

Comment: Read through the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/), especially [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate)

Comment: a similar question was aked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938655/jquery-moving-from-postion-x-to-position-y-slowly-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery .animate() is a way to go.
Documentation and examples are provided on http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Here is a [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cMbxS/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#abc;
  left:50px;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  margin:5px;
}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="left">&laquo;</button> <button id="right">&raquo;</button>
<div class="block"></div>

<script>
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```