# How can I slide a image up and down over a background image to create a scanning effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can across a nicely done scanning effect (on [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/)), where the image moves up and down over a background image.

They are using JavaScript to do this, but I wonder if this can be done with CSS, or if not how can I make this with JavaScript?

My code would be:

```
<style>
  #screenshot {
    margin: 8px auto 0 auto;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
    width: 300px;
    height: 225px;
    background: url("background-box.png") no-repeat center center;
    position: relative;
  }

  #scanner {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -19px;
  }
</style>

<div id="screenshot">
  <img src="scanner.png" alt="" id="scanner" />
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with javascript here is an working example for you what i made it. You must use jquery for catch scanner div.
Its endless animation and you can change speed and height.Speed must be miliseconds(1000ms is 1 sec) animatescanner(height,speed);

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/kfg9nutx/1/

Javascript :

```
x = 0;
xstate=0;
function animatescanner(height,speed){
setInterval(function(){ animateit(height); },speed);
}
function animateit(height){
    if(x==0){xstate=0}
    if(xstate==0){x++}
    if(xstate==1){x--}
    if(x==height){xstate=1}
    $("#scanner").css("top",x);
}
animatescanner(225,5);
```

Dont forget to include jquery.

Comment: Shokran Ibrahim for explaining your it and it works perfect .. i liked a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using jQuery animate function:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
<div id="screenshot">
  <img src="scanner.png" alt="" id="scanner" style="position:relative; left:0px;" />
</div>
```

and call javascript when you want the image to move:

```
<script>$("#scanner").animate({left:50}, 5000);</script>
```

you can animate using margins instead of position too.
another question from stack overflow...
[Moving from position A to position B slowly with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938655/jquery-moving-from-postion-x-to-position-y-slowly-animation)

Comment: Thank you thinkun Ltd and it might have minor error `<script>$("#scanner").animate({{left:50}, 5000});</script>` missing `{` and works good as well.