# Why do only some of my directional movement functions work?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I wonder if anyone can help me. I'm still learning jQuery and I don't understand why the "left" and "up" buttons are not working. It goes down and right perfectly. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dolu").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({
            marginTop:"100px"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#desno").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({
            marginLeft:"100px"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gore").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({
            marginBottom:"100px"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#levo").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({
            marginRight:"100px"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="gore">Up</button>
<button id="dolu">Down</button>
<button id="levo">Left</button>
<button id="desno">Right</button><br><br>
<div id="kocka" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:#D0D0D0; opacity:1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use just one `document.ready` function. Everything can be inside it.

Comment: What is not working, what do you see happening? You values need to be Integer: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting margins that have no effect on position. Placing a right margin where there's plenty of space doesn't do anything to the left position. Instead, change the left margin back, *or* subtract 100 from the existing left margin.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use String value for relative movement. Also reference `marginTop` and `marginLeft` only

```js
$(function() {
  var k = $("div#kocka");
  $("#dolu").click(function() {
    k.animate({
      marginTop: "+=100px"
    }, "slow");
  });
  $("#desno").click(function() {
    k.animate({
      marginLeft: "+=100px"
    }, "slow");
  });
  $("#gore").click(function() {
    k.animate({
      marginTop: "-=100px"
    }, "slow");
  });
  $("#levo").click(function() {
    k.animate({
      marginLeft: "-=100px"
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="gore">Up</button>
<button id="dolu">Down</button>
<button id="levo">Left</button>
<button id="desno">Right</button><br><br>
<div id="kocka" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:#D0D0D0; opacity:1">
</div>
```

Reference: [Moving from position A to position B slowly with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938655/moving-from-position-a-to-position-b-slowly-with-animation)