# Animate image growing and moving to center of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an svg image in a div, and I'd like to animate the image to grow to 80% screen height and move to the center of the parent div upon a function being called. How do I do this?

```js
function openNav(){
  $("#topnav").animate({height:'100%'})
  $("#title").fadeOut()
  //This is where I'd like the image animation
}

openNav();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind:wght@300;400&display=swap');
/* font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif; */

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: rgb(229,239,243);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(229,239,243,1) 0%, rgba(181,232,255,1) 100%);
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #2541B2;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px 2px 12px;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#logo{
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav" class="topnav">
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/ifn.svg" id="logo">
  <span id="title">Website</span>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Consider the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938655/moving-from-position-a-to-position-b-slowly-with-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this. Here is one based on using `.animate()`. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function openNav() {
    $("#topnav").animate({
      height: '100%'
    })
    $("#title").fadeOut();
    $("#logo").css("position", "absolute").animate({
      height: $(window).height() * .8,
      left: ($("#topnav").width() / 2) - ($("#logo").width() / 2)
    });
  }

  openNav();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind:wght@300;400&display=swap');

/* font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif; */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: rgb(229, 239, 243);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(229, 239, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(181, 232, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #2541B2;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px 2px 12px;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#logo {
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav" class="topnav">
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/ifn.svg" id="logo">
  <span id="title">Website</span>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: This almost works, however the image doesn't seem to move exactly to the middle of the page. Instead it seems to move too far to the right.